# How to print different tax rates in magento 2.1.6

Tags: magento2.1.6

I need to print different tax rates of Product Tax Class in Order Summary,order confirmation mail ,invoice..etc For example there are two type of tax rates in India Igst,Sgst .I need to print both separately and the total tax.

Answer (score 0):

Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings where set Yes to “Display Full Tax Summary”

If you want to display in orders,invoice and credit memo

Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax > orders,invoice and credit memo Settings where set Yes to “Display Full Tax Summary”